# Is there a non-messy way to chain the results of functions that return Option values?

Tags: rust, nullable, option-type

I have some code that looks like this:

```
f(a).and_then(|b| {
    g(b).and_then(|c| {
        h(c).map(|d| {
            do_something_with(a, b, c, d)
        })
    })
})
```

Where `f`, `g`, and `h` return `Option` values. I need to use all the intermediate values (`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`) in the `do_something_with` calculation. The indentation is very deep. Is there a better way to do this? Ideally it would look something like this (which of course doesn't work):

```
try {
    let b = f(a);
    let c = g(b);
    let d = h(c);
    do_something_with(a, b, c, d)
} rescue NonexistentValueException {
    None
}
```

Comment: do all the functions return the same option type? or do they change the type?

Comment: in case they are: here's a macro-free solution: http://is.gd/eItCTh any other solutions require value generics or variadic generics or some trait like [FixedSizeArray](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/array/trait.FixedSizeArray.html) just for tuples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Rust 1.22](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1220-2017-11-22)

The [question mark operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42917566/155423) now supports `Option`, so you can write your function as

```
fn do_something(a: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    let b = f(a)?;
    let c = g(b)?;
    let d = h(c)?;
    do_something_with(a, b, c, d) // wrap in Some(...) if this doesn't return an Option
}
```

## Rust 1.0

The Rust standard library defines a `try!` macro (and, equivalently, the `?` operator, as of [Rust 1.13](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1130-2016-11-10)) that solves this problem for `Result`. The macro looks like this:

```
macro_rules! try {
    ($expr:expr) => (match $expr {
        $crate::result::Result::Ok(val) => val,
        $crate::result::Result::Err(err) => {
            return $crate::result::Result::Err($crate::convert::From::from(err))
        }
    })
}
```

If the argument is `Err`, it returns from the function with that `Err` value. Otherwise, it evaluates to the value wrapped in `Ok`. The macro can only be used in a function that returns `Result`, because it returns the error it meets.

We can make a similar macro for `Option`:

```
macro_rules! try_opt {
    ($expr:expr) => (match $expr {
        ::std::option::Option::Some(val) => val,
        ::std::option::Option::None => return None
    })
}
```

You can then use this macro like this:

```
fn do_something(a: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    let b = try_opt!(f(a));
    let c = try_opt!(g(b));
    let d = try_opt!(h(c));
    do_something_with(a, b, c, d) // wrap in Some(...) if this doesn't return an Option
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Inspired from the concept of `try!` for Result, let's wrap our own macro to early-return from the scope if the monad drops to None.

```
macro_rules! get(
    ($e:expr) => (match $e { Some(e) => e, None => return None })
);
```

(Stolen from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/23amxp/is_there_an_equivalent_to_the_try_macro_for_option/))

Now you can run your code linearly:

```
fn blah() -> Option<...> { // ... is the return type of do_something_with()
    let a = 123;
    let b = get!(f(a));
    let c = get!(g(b));
    let d = get!(h(c));
    do_something_with(a, b, c, d)
}
```

([runnable gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3c8b998f1e96872994b))