# What is this question mark operator about?

Tags: rust, syntax

I'm reading [the documentation for `File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html):

```
//..
let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?;
//..
```

What is the `?` in this line? I do not recall seeing it in the Rust Book before.

Comment: Note that the description of ? has been included in 2018 book https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html

Answer (score 355, accepted):

As you may have noticed, Rust does not have exceptions. It has panics, but their use for error-handling is discouraged (they are meant for unrecoverable errors).

In Rust, error handling uses [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). A typical example would be:

```
fn halves_if_even(i: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        Ok(i / 2)
    } else {
        Err(/* something */)
    }
}

fn do_the_thing(i: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let i = match halves_if_even(i) {
        Ok(i) => i,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };

    // use `i`
}
```

This is great because:

- when writing the code you cannot accidentally forget to deal with the error,
- when reading the code you can immediately see that there is a potential for error right here.

It's less than ideal, however, in that it is very verbose. This is where the question mark operator `?` comes in.

The above can be rewritten as:

```
fn do_the_thing(i: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let i = halves_if_even(i)?;

    // use `i`
}
```

which is much more concise.

What `?` does here is equivalent to the `match` statement above with an addition. In short:

1. It unpacks the `Result` if OK
2. It *returns* the error if not, calling [`From::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from) on the error value to potentially convert it to another type.

It's a bit magic, but error handling needs some magic to cut down the boilerplate, and unlike exceptions it is immediately visible which function calls may or may not error out: those that are adorned with `?`.

One example of the magic is that this also works for `Option`:

```
// Assume
// fn halves_if_even(i: i32) -> Option<i32>

fn do_the_thing(i: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    let i = halves_if_even(i)?;

    // use `i`
}
```

The `?` operator, [stabilized in Rust version 1.13.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/31954) is powered by the (unstable) [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait.

See also:

- [Is the question mark operator ? equivalent to the try! macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40545332/155423)
- [Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555477/155423)

Comment: it would be nice if you could extend your answer a little bit, e.g. discuss that the return type of the function must match the type you try to "unwrap", e.g. `Result` or `Option`.

Answer (score 29):

It is a postfix operator that unwraps `Result<T, E>` and `Option<T>` values.

If applied to `Result<T, E>`, it unwraps the result and gives you the inner value, propagating the error to the calling function.

```rust
let number = "42".parse::<i32>()?;
println!("{:?}", number); // 42
```

When applied to an `Option<T>`, it propagates `None` to the caller, leaving you the content of the Some branch to deal with.

```rust
let val = Some(42)?;
println!("{:?}", val); // 42
```

The `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` like so:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let number = "42".parse::<i32>()?;
    println!("{:?}", number);
    Ok(())
}
```

It is a convenience offered by Rust, which eliminates boilerplate code and makes function's implementation simpler.

Comment: not to be confused with actual `.unwrap()` which panics in the case of an error.

Answer (score 13):

It is used for `propagating errors`. Sometimes we write code that might fail but we do not want to catch and handle error immediately. Your code will not be readable if you have too much code to handle the error in every place. Instead, if an error occurs, we might want to let our caller deal with it. We want errors to propagate up the call stack.

```
 // file type is Result if "?" is not used
 // file:Result<File,Error>
 let mut file = File::create("foo.txt");

 // file type is File if "?" is used
 // file:File
 let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?;
 // if an error occurs, code after this line will not be executed
 // function will return the error
 // if we do not return here, the program will continue execution even though an error occurred. This could lead to unexpected behavior or incorrect results.
```

The behavior of `?` depends on whether this function returns a successful result or an error result:

- If it is a success, it unwraps the Result to get the success value inside. Value is assigned to the variable `file`
- If the result is an error, the error is NOT assigned to the variable `file`. Error is returned by the function to the caller

Using `?` same as this code

```
let mut file = match File::create("foo.txt") {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't create {}: {}", display, why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };
```

`?` also works similarly with the Option type. In a function that returns Option, you
can use ? to unwrap a value and return early in the case of None :

Comment: This answer is solid, but I would like to throw out there, using `?` is not the same as calling `panic!()`. That would terminate the program. Using `?` is more akin to calling `return Err(why)`.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are all great! I would like to give a small code snippet to demo the use of `From::from()` behand this question mark:

```rust
fn _parse(str: &str) -> Result<i32, &str> {
    if let Ok(num) = str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(num)
    } else {
        Err(str)
    }
}
```

```rust
fn parse(str: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    let num = _parse(str)?;
    println!("{}", num);
    Ok(())
}
```

The use of `?` in function `parse()` can be manually rewritten as:

```rust
fn parse(str: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    match _parse(str) {
        Ok(n) => {
            println!("{}", n);
            Ok(())
        }
        Err(str) => Err(<String as From<&str>>::from(str)),
    }
}
```