# How can I propagate the errors in Rust?

Tags: if-statement, rust

Is there a nice way to propagate errors in Rust? 
E. g., I'd like to refactor the following code to avoid nested errors:

```
.for_each(|record| {
    match f1() {
        Ok(a1) => match f2() {
            Ok(a2) => match f3() {
                Ok(_) => {}
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
                }
            },
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            }
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
        }
    };
    Ok(())
})
```

The question is not a duplicate because I've got a `for_each` operator which complicates a situation for me. And when I put `?` to `f2` I actually receive the following error:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<std::io::Error>` is not implemented for `grpcio::error::Error`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about)

Comment: @hellow thanks for the suggestion, but I can't understand how I use `?` together with `for_each`.

Comment: Don't use a `for_each` then but a classic for loop :)

Comment: Are f1, f2 and f3 have the same error type ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use functional style loops + error propagation because you're inside a closure.

Comment: @Boiethios Actually we can't tell that you cannot use it in closure, it is a closure that doesn't return `Result`.(If we are talking about `iterators` in rust core),  That's why we can't use error propagating.

Comment: @ÖmerErden they return `Result<Vec<u8>/String/String, io:Error>`, but the error type is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain your functions in the success scenario with `and_then` and map their errors with `map_err`.

Like here you can chain them:

```
let result = f1().and_then(|_| {
    f2().and_then(|_| {
        f3().and_then(|_| {
            println!("All functions are succeed");
            Ok(())
        })
    })
});
```

Here you will have the `result` variable if the error occurs.

Then you can match this error with `if let Err(error)` statement like following:

```
if let Err(error) = result {
    println!("Problem occurred: {:?}", error);
};
```

There is also possibility to throw your error to upper levels with `try!` macro or `?` operator like following:

```
fn throw_error() -> Result<String, MyError> {
    let string_val = "will not be returned".to_string();

    Err(MyError::thrownError)?;
    Ok(string_val)
}
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=476ca7447d2e2044420f1d5e158055d5) you can test and play a little bit more to understand the concepts.