# Options, and_then() and tuples

Tags: rust

I'm convinced there is a way to handle this 'cleanly', I am just not quite figuring it out.

```
use git2::Repository;

// Prints out the current branch and sha if it exists.
fn report_repo() -> () {
    Repository::open(".")
        .ok()
        .and_then(branch_and_sha)
        .and_then(|branch_sha| => {  // Fails here with E0061
            let (branch, sha) = branch_sha;
            println!("Branch={} sha={}", branch, sha);
            None
        });
}

fn branch_and_sha(repo: Repository) -> Option<(String, String)> {
    match repo.head().ok() {
        Some(reference) => {
            match (reference.name(),  reference.target()){
                (Some(branch), Some(sha)) => Some((branch.to_string(), sha.to_string())),
                _ => None
            }
        },
        None => None
    }
}
```

The error that arises is [E0061](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0061), and I think it's because the 'value' in the Option returned from `branch_and_sha()` is a tuple. `branch_and_sha()` effectively says, "If there is a repository, get it's reference, and if that exists, if it has both a name (branch) and target (sha), return an `Option<(String, String)>` with that info - otherwise return `None`. And the reporting function wants to do something *if* all of the `Repository`, branch and sha can be found - and nothing otherwise. (It shouldn't error or panic.)

To some degree this is contrived - it's an example of an optimistic reporting function similar to several I'd like to write. I'm looking for a clean, idiomatic way to do it. The key thrust is 'several depths and several branches could return `None` which should cause a no-op, and otherwise make specific (leaf) info available.' The specific error is how I should be handling the `and_then` function, which is surprisingly difficult to find similar problems about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you have a minor typo. Closures in Rust don't use `=>`. So your closure should look more like

```
.and_then(|branch_sha|  {  // Note: No => here
  let (branch, sha) = branch_sha;
  println!("Branch={} sha={}", branch, sha);
  None
});
```

Then the error we get is

```
  --> so_cleanly.rs:15:10
   |
15 |         .and_then(|branch_sha| {
   |          ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `U` declared on the associated function `and_then`
   |
```

[`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) is declared with two generic arguments: `U` and `F` (technically, there's also `T`, but that's determined by the type of the receiver `self`, so we won't worry about it). Now, `F` is the type of the closure and is always determined by the argument. On the other hand, `U` is the return type of the closure.

The closure must return an `Option<U>`. Rust needs to look at the closure and determine what its return type is. What does the closure return? It returns `None`, and `None` can be `Option<U>` for any `U` in existence. Rust doesn't know which one to use. We need to tell it. We could do that on the line we return `None` from

```
None as Option<()>
```

or in the `and_then` call itself.

```
.and_then::<(), _>(|branch_sha| { ... })
```

However, the compiler is making a very valid point. `and_then` and company produce a result of type `Option`, which you're ignoring. You're writing a piece of code which has side effects and doesn't produce a value, which is sensible, but you're using a functional interface intended for returning values. It *can* be done, but it's probably not idiomatic. I had to look at your code a few times before realizing that the `()` return value was not a typo.

One option is to return `Option<()>` from your `report_repo`. The `()` on the inside indicates that we don't care about anything except the side effects, and the `Option` lets the caller of `report_repo` handle (or ignore) any errors that occur during the process, whereas your current function simply suppresses all errors unconditionally.

```
fn report_repo() -> Option<()> {
  Repository::open(".")
    .ok()
    .and_then(branch_and_sha)
    .map(|branch_sha| {
      let (branch, sha) = branch_sha;
      println!("Branch={} sha={}", branch, sha);
      // Implicit return of () here, which we could do explicitly if we wanted
    })
}
```

I've made several subtle changes here. The return type is `Option<()>` now. In accordance with that, there's no semicolon at the end of the line inside the function (we're returning that value). Finally, the last `and_then` is a [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map), since the final step can't fail and simply does some work on `Some`.

That's an improvement, but it's probably still not how I'd write this function.

Instead, if you're performing code for side effects, consider using the [`?` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about), which does `and_then` and `map` shenanigans but keeps the control flow relatively linear. `and_then` and its friends are great for constructing values, but the point of your function is that it should read like a sequence of instructions, not a constructor for a value. This is how I would write that function.

```
fn report_repo() -> Option<()> {
  let repo = Repository::open(".").ok()?;
  let (branch, sha) = branch_and_sha(repo)?;
  println!("Branch={} sha={}", branch, sha);
  Some(())
}
```

Each line that ends in a `?` effectively says "If this thing is `None`, return `None` now. Otherwise, keep going." But a cursory glance of the code reads "open the repo, branch and sha, and then print", which is exactly what you want people to see at a glance.

If we wanted to be really proper about this, we should probably return `Result<(), Error>`, where `Error` is some more detailed error type, but that's overkill for this simple example snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! The typo definitely misdirected me (I had been trying to use a match statement and must have left it in). The type signature is where I was getting hung up.

Answer (score 2):

You can chose an `if let` style too, you do not need the option value so just stop using them at some point it feels more comfortable:

```
fn report_repo() {
    if let Some((branch, sha)) = Repository::open(".").ok().and_then(branch_and_sha) {
        println!("Branch={} sha={}", branch, sha);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had not really internalized the if let construct... thanks for pointing this out! I think it's definitely a more concise option than the matching I'd been doing in, say, the branch_and_sha function.