# Why can the ? operator convert a &str into a Box<dyn Error>?

Tags: rust

Please consider the following two functions:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn foo() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let x: Result<Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>>, &str> = Err("error");
    x?
}

fn bar() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err("error")
}
```

`foo()` will compile, but `bar()` won’t.

I guess I understand why `bar()` doesn’t work: We expect an object implementing the `Error` trait in a `Box` but we pass a `&str` which neither implements `Error` nor is it in a `Box`.

I wonder why `foo()` compiles though. Won’t the `?` operator also try to convert the `&str` into a `Box<dyn Error>` in this case? Why does it succeed?

Comment: in `foo()` the `?` operator converts the error to the correct type, while in `bar()` you are not using `?`. It succeeds, because there is such `impl`: `impl<'a> From<&str> for Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'a> {
`

Comment: `fn baz() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> { Err("error".into()) }` compiles, and you can think `foo()` as being equivalent to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works because there is an

```
impl From<&'_ str> for Box<dyn Error>
```

[in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20str%3E-2). This is what the `?` [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about) to convert from a `&str` to a `Box<dyn Error>`. This implementation in turn uses the [`impl From<String> for Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-2) in std, which [has a "hidden" type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/error.rs.html#240-280) that uses the `String` as its description when implementing `Error`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `bar` work by calling `from` on `Error`:

```rust
fn bar() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err(Error::from("error"))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You need to say `Err(Box::<dyn Error>::from("error"))`.