# Expected type `Method` found enum `Result<_, MethodError>`

Tags: rust, program-entry-point

I am trying to convert a `&str` to an `enum`, but got the error `Expected type Method   found enum Result<_, MethodError>` at this line `Err(e) => Err(e)`. How to properly return an error in this case?

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Method {
    GET,
    DELETE,
    POST,
    PUT,
    HEAD,
    CONNECT,
    OPTIONS,
    TRACE,
    PATCH,
}

impl FromStr for Method {
    type Err = MethodError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s {
            "GET" => Ok(Self::GET),
            "DELETE" => Ok(Self::DELETE),
            "POST" => Ok(Self::POST),
            "PUT" => Ok(Self::PUT),
            "HEAD" => Ok(Self::HEAD),
            "CONNECT" => Ok(Self::CONNECT),
            "OPTIONS" => Ok(Self::OPTIONS),
            "TRACE" => Ok(Self::TRACE),
            "PATCH" => Ok(Self::PATCH),
            _ => Err(MethodError),
        }
    }
}

pub struct MethodError;

let method:&str = "GET";

let methodE =  match method.parse::<Method>() {
    Ok(method) => method,
    Err(e) => Err(e),
};
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about)

Comment: sorry this is a bit unclear... you are in `main` when you say "return an error", do you want your `main` to have a return type? Or do you just want to catch the error in your `match` and do something with it (like print it)?

Comment: `match` is an expression, so all returning match arms have to return the same type of value. Both your match arms return, one returns a value of type `Method` and one returns  a value of type `Result<_, MethodError>`. Those are not the same types, and hence the compiler error. (A match arm which does not return, calls `panic` or something that results in a call to `panic`. Maybe there are more possibilities to "not return" I don't know of.)

Comment: @typetetris Early return with `return` is another way to leave the match without evaluating to a value. `return` exits the function in which the `match` appears, and so if a match arm ends with a `return` it is ignored for the purposes of type checking.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Sorry for being unclear. I am trying to use `Result` in `main`, and catch the error in my match.

Comment: @cdhowie Thank you. It does not answer my question, `let methodE: Method = method.parse()?;` did not work too.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I've figured it out. I added an answer.

Comment: @Peter It does answer your question, if you look at the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's comments, I've figured it out:

1. `main` needs to return `Result<(), MethodError>`
2. `return` keyword is necessary in match arm `Err(e) => return Err(e)`

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Method {
    GET,
    DELETE,
    POST,
    PUT,
    HEAD,
    CONNECT,
    OPTIONS,
    TRACE,
    PATCH,
}

impl FromStr for Method {
    type Err = MethodError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s {
            "GET" => Ok(Self::GET),
            "DELETE" => Ok(Self::DELETE),
            "POST" => Ok(Self::POST),
            "PUT" => Ok(Self::PUT),
            "HEAD" => Ok(Self::HEAD),
            "CONNECT" => Ok(Self::CONNECT),
            "OPTIONS" => Ok(Self::OPTIONS),
            "TRACE" => Ok(Self::TRACE),
            "PATCH" => Ok(Self::PATCH),
            _ => Err(MethodError),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MethodError;

fn main() -> Result<(), MethodError> {
  let method:&str = "GET";
  
  let methodE =  match method.parse::<Method>() {
      Ok(method) => method,
      Err(e) => return Err(e),
  };
  
  // this works too: let methodE: Method =  method.parse()?;
  
  Ok(())
}
```