# Idiomatic way to return a value other than a Result or Option from a function when an option is None?

Tags: error-handling, rust, idioms

I would like to do this:

```
fn foo(bar: Option<...>) -> ... {
    if let None = bar { // bar is None. No need to go any further
        return ...
    }

    /* Do some complex calculation assuming bar is Some(...) */
}
```

This kind of approach is fine in untyped languages and even some typed ones like TypeScript and (if memory serves me right) Swift but it won't do for Rust.

What is the idiomatic way to do this that works for return types other than `Option` and `Result`? I could do:

```
if let Some(...) = bar {
    /* complex calculation */
} else {
    return ...
}
```

It seems akin to a lot of unreadable nested if-else clauses with a lot of indentation in the long run.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is there a non-messy way to chain the results of functions that return Option values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31172451/155423) and [How do you unwrap a Result on Ok or return from the function on Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344951/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator

Comment: @Stargateur What you linked to says: "_The ? Operator Can Only Be Used in Functions That Return Result"_. Perhaps i was unclear but my -> ... signature refers to any arbitrary type.

Comment: I linked to [an answer that applies to any type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344951/155423) (yes, it says "Result" in the title, but read the answers). What's insufficient with that answer?

Comment: @Shepmaster oh s**t only looked ad the first link then got all busy defending myself. The second link does indeed seam to answer my question

Comment: Do you feel like this can be marked as a duplicate then?

Comment: @Shepmaster yeah sure, go ahead.

Comment: @Hugobastas Rust is *comparatively* new. The [top 200 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/960749/questions-with-most-views) have between 57K and 6K views.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, kinda unescesary comment on my part.

Comment: @Hugobastas oh nevermind, [example of how I will do it](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e16a896c1a435af4d4fda5b93c73d085)